# relative Path for file in struts 2 Webapplication

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, hashmap, freemarker

I've got one problem. I'm working on a web Application using Struts (Struts 2 Framework).

I created a Freemarker template file for every single user and save it in

```
webapps/mail/mailEn/customer.ftl
```

Now, when the page is called, I must look if a customer.ftl So I try looking after it in my java class like this:
( when i use local direcory path C://... it works)

```
 MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = null;
 try {
 textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

//FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File ("D:/Workspace//Projectname///web///styles/");

 FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader (new File("\\mail\\mailEn"));       TemplateLoader[] loaders = new TemplateLoader[] { ftl1 };

 MultiTemplateLoader mtl = new MultiTemplateLoader(loaders);
 cfg.setTemplateLoader(mtl);
 cfg.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapper());
 Template template = cfg.getTemplate("customerInfo.ftl");
 Map<String, String> rootMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
 rootMap.put("image1", "images/LOGO.jpg");
 rootMap.put("recipient", "aaaa");
 rootMap.put("address", "xxxx");
 rootMap.put("contact", "yyyy");
 rootMap.put("country", "uuuu");
 rootMap.put("sender", "rrrrr");

 Writer out = new StringWriter();
 template.process(rootMap, out);
 textBodyPart.setContent(out.toString(),Constants.TEXT_HTML);
}
```

With the absolute path `(D:/....)` it works without problems. But this can't be the 
solution, because when Ive finished this web-app, I will have an war-file which will be put on a server and the absolute path will be wrong then. So I need a relative path which will always work!

I'm working with Eclipse at this moment. When I try to use the path above (/../.. ....), 
the file I'm looking for can never be found. (I tried to go up to the home path of the 
project and then to the folder mail, where the file is)

I tried out many different paths like ./web/mail/ , ../../../../../web/styles, and so on, 
but I never found the file I was looking for.

If anyone could give me a hint what to do, I would be very grateful!

Thank you!

Comment: Put them into `resources` folder and use `getResourceAsStream` method.

Comment: Instead of `getResourceAsStream` he can just use `ClassTemplateLoader`. Otherwise, if FreeMarker can't load the template itself, it can't cache the `Template` for you.

Comment: i tried using ClassTemplateLoader but its not working. its says File Not Found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `WebappTemplateLoader` (or maybe `ClassTemplateLoader`). `FileTemplateLoader` is not a good fit for this, as in theory you can't even know if the `war` file will be extracted on the server, and if it's not extracted, you surely won't have a directory to point to.

Comment: what does ClassTemplateLoader do by specifying the class name and the path in it ?
also 
now i'm using FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File(request.getRealPath(\mail\mailEn ))); and its working fine but request.getRealPath() is depricated method so is there any other alternative to this ?

Comment: `getRealPath` is not deprecated in `ServletContext`, but it can still return `null` if the `war` is not unpacked. As of `ClassTemplateLoader`, see the JavaDoc: http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/ClassTemplateLoader.html#ClassTemplateLoader%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Can it cause problems in future if i use request.getRealPath(\mail\mailEn) ie request.getRealPath deprecated method in my project

Comment: As I said, yes, because `war`-s are not always extracted on servers, and then `getRealPath` will return `null`, because there's no file to point to. Typically they are extracted though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406118/error-giving-freemarker-image-tag-src-and-template-directory-path (Question in detail)

Comment: i used request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(mail\mailEn);

Answer (score 0):

actully your file are getting stored in the temp folder (application server/os) so i suggest to you `

```
request.getRequestedURI() + "/" + FILE_PATH`
```

Say: you saved "file.txt" at "URL:PORT/file/file.txt" which refers to the tmp folder in fact and it gets deleted once the server is restarted or application undeployed. make sure the folder you are using to save is outside web-inf

Comment: i did FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader (new File(request.getRequestedURI()+"\\mail\\mailEn")); it gave me correct path "/Web/mail/mailEn" in console but still giving me error file not found. my directory is ProjectWeb >> src >> main >> webapp >> mail >>mailEn >> customer.ftl

Comment: it gives java.io.FileNotFoundException: \ProjectWeb\mail\mailEn does not exist.

Comment: now i'm using  FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File(request.getRealPath(\mail\mailEn ))); and its working fine but request.getRealPath() is depricated method so is there any other alternative to this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution(adjustment)**

I used `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath()`

In a class for example MessageUtility i used

```
final private static String MAIL = ResourceBundle.getBundle("cfg_webapp").getString("mails.folder");

String mailpath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(MAIL);

FileTemplateLoader ftl1 = new FileTemplateLoader(new File(mailpath));
```

In cfg_webapp.properties i defined

```
## Mails
mails.folder=mails
```

It gets the path from -----  src/main/webapps/mails/customer.ftl

thanks all.